# Probability Distribution like x^2

Tags: numpy, probability, probability-distribution

I searched a while and could't find any probability distribution that fits my needs. The Distribution should look something like the function `c1 * x^2 + c2`. The closest I could find in numpy is the Beta Distribution with alpha=0.5 and beta=0.5. But I don't like the plain area in the middle of it. Someone has any ideas?

Comment: As written, this question can only invite people randomly trying things in an attempt to discover whatever it is the OP likes, which isn't a recipe for a good SO question.

Comment: *"... could't find any probability distribution that fits my needs."*  Explain your needs in more detail; *"something like the function c1 * x^2 + c2"* is vague, as is *"I don't like the plain area in the middle of it"*.

Comment: Also, once you've figured out a more precise set of requirements for the distribution, I think the question will be more appropriate for the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: could you provide picture of the histogram?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own distributions using [scipy.stats.rv_continous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html)

Example of how to use it:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

def my_pdf_function(x, c1, c2):
    return (x**2 * c1 + c2)

class cuadratic_distribution(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        # For example: c1=1, c2=2/3 (normalized between x=0 and x=1)
        return my_pdf_function(x, c1=1, c2=2/3)

my_pdf = cuadratic_distribution(a=0, b=1, name='my_pdf')

my_pdf.cdf([-1, 0.4, 2])
>>> array([0.   , 0.316, 1.   ])
```

Note that you should set appropiately the boundaries of the distribution (`a` and `b`), and the correspondant values of c1 and c2 to ensure 0 < P(x) < 1 and that the integral of P(x) yields 1